# Database: Sorting on non-indexed column

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, indexing, sql-order-by

Does creating index on a column which is there in sort order improves performance? I need to know this for Mysql, Postgresql and Oracle database.

E.g query:

```
select * from article_comments where article_id = 245 order by date_created desc limit 30;
```

In article_comments table, article_id is an indexed field, where as date_created is not.
If we create an index on date_created, will it improve performance. 
Table size is around 5-7 million rows.

Comment: You can simply test it. On Oracle you can even make `ALTER INDEX index INVISIBLE / VISIBLE;` which enables you to test without creating and dropping the index again and again.

Comment: Is your question, "Do indexes improve performance?"

Comment: I'd expect to be {article_id, date_created} to be *at least* (part of) a candidate key.

Answer (score 2):

> Does creating index on a column which is there in sort order improves
>   performance?

A general answer is: it depends on many factors, esspecialy on conditions used in WHERE clause.
In case of your query an index on `date_created` column doesn't eliminate a sort operation due to `where article_id = 245` clause.
In this case you need to create a multicolum index in order to skip sorting:
`CREATE INDEX somename ON article_comments(article_id, date_created DESC)`

Comment: The _entire_ `WHERE` clause was handled by that index; the `ORDER BY` could still be handled by the rest of the index columns.  Hence, the order of the index rows allows the sort pass to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell only for Oracle. Yes an Index **can** make your sorting faster.

In this example [Function-Based Index for Language-Dependent Sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS261) Oracle shows an index which intention is **only** to improve performance of an `ORDER BY` operation.

Another example regarding sorting is shown here: [Full Index Scan](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT88838)